# How to draw a jpeg/png image using QPainter.drawImage on a background form with jpeg/png image in Qt?

Tags: c++, image, qt

I created a **form** in **Qt** with **QLabel** conataining the *.png* image as the background image. Now I want to  draw a *.png* image over that background *.png* image . I am able to draw the image on a background, If there is no .png/.jpeg image as the background i.e., it's possible on a plain form without any background image. whenever i try to draw the image using **QPainter.drawimage** on the background image, the background image is only being visible i.e, the background static image(.png) is superposing the image('.png' using QPainter.drawImage) that is dynamically drawn.

Can anyone please let me know a solution to this approach. If not please let me know some other approach. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to subclass the QLabel, add additional method(s) to accept foreground/background pixmaps, and override the paintEvent function.

The additional methods could look something like this:

```
// literally the same thing as setPixmap but constructed a new function to be clearer
void CustomLabel::setBackground(const QPixmap & pixmap)
{ 
    // will handle sizing the label to the size of the image
    // and will additionally handle drawing of the background
    this->setPixmap(pixmap);
} 

void CustomLabel::setForeground(const QPixmap & pixmap)
{ 
    // create member variable that points to foreground image
    this->foreground = pixmap;
}
```

Then, override the paintEvent function:

```
void CustomLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e)
{
    // use the base class QLabel paintEvent to draw the background image.
    QLabel::paintEvent(e); 

    // instantiate a local painter
    QPainter painter(this);

    // draw foreground image over the background
    // draws the foreground starting from the top left at point 0,0 of the label.
    // You can supply a different offset or source/destination rects to achieve the 
    // blitting effect you want.
    painter.drawPixmap(QPoint(0,0),this->foreground); 

}
```

... And you can then the label can be used as follows:

```
//instantiate a custom label (or whatever you choose to call it)
label = new CustomLabel();

// use the additional methods created as part of your CustomLabel class
label->setBackground(QPixmap("background.png"));
label->setForeground(QPixmap("foreground.png"));
```

Additionally, the CustomLabel class could be expanded upon further to accept more than just a single background and foreground image. For example, a `setPixmaps(QVector<QPixmap>)` function could store the vector of images it was passed, resize the label to the first image in the vector, then utilize the paintEvent function to draw all the images handed to it.

Keep in mind the foreground images should be of lesser or equal size than the background image in order for the foreground image not to be cropped. (As QPainter will not manage resizing the widget its painting.)

EDIT:

> Now I just want to overlay the background with a new image(size 30x30)
>   using 'Qpainter.drawImage' that moves on the background
>   image(1366x768). It's something like moving a mousepointer on the
>   screen in which the screen being the background form(.png image on a
>   Qlabel) & the mousepointer being the newimage dynamically drawn using
>   'Qpainter.drawImage'

To accomplish this you could make a simple edit/overload to the setForeground function and modify the paintEvent function like so:

```
void CustomLabel::setForeground(const QPixmap & pixmap, const QPointF & offset)
{ 
    // create member variable that points to foreground image
    this->foreground = pixmap;

    // establish the offset from the top left corner of the background image
    // to draw the top left corner of the foreground image.
    this->foregroundOffset = offset;
} 

void CustomLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e)
{
    // use the base class QLabel paintEvent to draw the background image.
    QLabel::paintEvent(e); 

    // instantiate a local painter
    QPainter painter(this);

    // draw foreground image over the background using given offset
    painter.drawPixmap(this->foregroundOffset,this->foreground); 

}
```

Comment: But I have a background Ui(1366x768) & it changes based on its functionality(separate) and it can't be changed. Now I just want to overlay the background with a new image(size 30x30) using 'Qpainter.drawImage' that moves on the background image(1366x768). It's something like moving a mousepointer on the screen in which the screen being the background form(.png image on a Qlabel) & the mousepointer being the  newimage dynamically drawn using 'Qpainter.drawImage'